# Extract subset of dictionaries inside a list of dictionaries until particular key is found

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of dict

```
dict = [{'a':'1'},{'b':'2'},{'c':'3'},{'Stop':'appending'},{'d':'4'},{'e':'5'},{'f':'6'}]

dict1 = [{'a':'1'},{'b':'2'},{'c':'3'},{'d':'4'},{'Stop':'appending'},{'e':'5'},{'f':'6'}]
```

I want to extract all list elements until key 'Stop' is found and append it to new dictionary

Expected output:

```
new_dict = [{'a':'1'},{'b':'2'},{'c':'3'}]

new_dict1 = [{'a':'1'},{'b':'2'},{'c':'3'},{'d':'4'}]
```

**Code:**

```
temp_dict = [] 
for i in range(0,len(list)):     
    for key,value in list[i].items():         
        if key == 'Stop':             
            break          
        temp_dict.append(list[i])
```

Comment: itertools.takewhile

Comment: This is append all elements after 'stop' also

Comment: write a function to find the index of `'stop'` key in your list of dicts then slice the list using index

Comment: What is your question? Is something wrong with your code?

Comment: Isn't a dictionary `unordered`?

Comment: @YashvanderBamel What does that matter?

Comment: Sorry my bad, I just presumed the list to be dictionary by the variable name:(

Answer (score 1):

It's already in standard library

```
import itertools

dict1 = [{'a':'1'},{'b':'2'},{'c':'3'},{'d':'4'},{'Stop':'appending'},{'e':'5'},{'f':'6'}]

res = list(itertools.takewhile(lambda x: "Stop" not in x, dict1))

print(res)
```

output:

```
[{'a': '1'}, {'b': '2'}, {'c': '3'}, {'d': '4'}]
```

Comment: @mickmackusa maybe it's a duplicate question, it should be a duplicate, cuz it's really basic case, but I'm unable to find something quite similar in reasonable time. And I don't think this snippet is "unexplained", it's simple as a pie.

Comment: No worries.  I really appreciate that you hunted. Not enough people do this. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `enumerate()` to get the index of the element matching the key `Stop` and then used list slicing on top of that:

```
dic = [{'a':'1'},{'b':'2'},{'c':'3'},{'Stop':'appending'},{'d':'4'},{'e':'5'},{'f':'6'}]
index = next(index for index, elt in enumerate(dic) if elt.get('Stop'))
new_dic = dic[0:index]  # [{'a': '1'}, {'b': '2'}, {'c': '3'}]
```

Also, don't use `dict` keyword for object names to avoid shadowing built-in primitives.

---

Update: If you want to just skip the element with key `Stop` and take all others then update the above slicing operation as:

```
new_dic = dic[0:index] + dic[index+1:] # [{'a': '1'}, {'b': '2'}, {'c': '3'}, {'d': '4'}, {'e': '5'}, {'f': '6'}]
```

Comment: Value inside the key 'Stop'  can change dictionary to dictionary..

Comment: @AnandThirtha, you can use mix of `enumerate`, `list comprehension` and `next` to get the index of the element with key `Stop` and then used slicing to get the result. please see my updated answer.

Comment: @Manuel I don't python.  I don't know how to search for a duplicate.  I rely on those who are SMEs in the tag to be able to find good duplicates for basic questions. (assuming this is a basic question)

Answer (score 0):

First find the index of the elements that have 'Stop' like a key, and after that just slice the list to the first of those index.

Try:

```
inds = [i for i in range(len(dict1)) if 'Stop' in dict1[i].keys()]
new_dict1 = dict1[:inds[0]]
```

Also, I think you should choice better names for your lists, especially for the first, `dict` is a reserved word in python.

Comment: I cannot hardcode the value 'appending' as it might vary dict to dict..

Comment: Look at the edit, I made an update for this

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.